# What are the verses and ahadith that support the idea of possession by a jinn?

Tags: jinn

So I know there is a verse in the Quran that those who indulge in riba are going to be standing on Day of Judgement as if they were beaten into insanity by Shaytan. However, I don't think this verse can exactly justify jinn possession. Is there any other verses or hadiths that can help support jinn possession?

Comment: I think you have not done any research. Jinn Possession is  very real. We have 100s and thousands of cases every year of people possessed with jinn. I might ansewer this question later on as I know probably more than others, at the minuet i need to take my ruqyah bath for the jinn that is possessing me.

Comment: @AsanRamzan Are you like okay? Haha.

Comment: Yes, this ruqyah plan I have takes up all of my day. I was telling my sister and mother I feel like I need a secretary

Comment: This is not a discussion form and we are not here to tell you which group of scholars is correct in a disputed matter.

Comment: @SabrinsSims I can confirm there are verses or ahadith about it. Jinn possession is real and there are many phenomenon about it such as a male possessed talks like a female (vice versa), being able to speak many languages, etc. Being possessed is different from having a mental condition in Islam.

Answer (score -1):

Oftern jinn possession and schizophrenia get muddled up. How then to untangle and discern between two. And it is necessary that you do this as the wrong diagnosis mean you give the wrong medicine. This is partically the case if you miss-diagnose a person possessed by jinn as antipsychotics can have many side effects like insomnia, severe headaches, nausea and vomiting, drowsiness and these are common side effects there are a lot more side effects and some of these are severe like early on set of degenerative diseases such as diabetes and also increased risk of breast cancer (I can go into the science behind this as I have two degrees in medical reseach, but that would be going off the tangent).

Now the way to tell the difference is that:

1)they may have symptoms that cannot be from schizophrenia
2)they get a reaction to ruqyah treatment such as recition to particular verses of the Quran.

see this YouTube video as a case study of a sister possessed with jinn, take some notes:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jFdGaru-3dc&t=662s

You will see she has both of above points,

1. she is speaking all of a sudden in a different language, this cannot happen by chance nor would one except it from schizophrenia
   2)she reacts to the Quran and the jinn actually starts to speak on her tongue.

And the nice thing I like adout this video, it is linked to this topic i.e. misdigonsis of jinn possession with scizaphinia

Mind the spelling mistakes I wrote this while reciting surah yasin, but I really do think you need to research more on this topic especially when posting question as this information is already available. Another useful raqi you could look up is Tim Humble, to increase your knowldge on jinn possession.

There is a hadith that says that shaytan flows in the blood of Adam

Anas ibn Malik reported: The Messenger of Allah, peace and blessings be upon him, said, “Verily, Satan flows through the human being like the flowing of blood.”

Source: Ṣaḥīḥ Muslim 2174

And don't think this is a metaphor as I and many other have had hijama on the head to suck it out the head like a vacuum sucks up dust, by sucking out the blood. Whilst I did this the jinn was making my finger move out of control and I could really control them myself

From what you can do with black magic it is obvious jinns can possess people e.g. I know a person who is possessed by a jinn and it can read what that person is thinking, how would this be possible if the jinn was not in his head.

Is this not clear enough proof for you.

And scholars are not educated in jinn possession or black magic as these things are not on their syllabus